# embed <br> tags in textarea field populated from MysQL database?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I am displaying a log as inside a read-only `<textarea>` field inside a modal, which is populated with data coming from my MySQL database.
Right below this textarea I have another writeable `<textarea>` field in which the user is supposed to enter any update to the log, which then is appended to the existing log record.

All of this works fine, but the problem starts when the user enters linebreaks inside the writeable textarea, which are then printed as `<br>` tags inside the textarea field.

Is there any way for me to embed the tags and turn them into actual linebreaks?

[image]

EDIT:
below the code I use to extract the 'old' content of the `Action` column in my database and then append the newly entered content from the textarea

```
// select 'Follow Up Action' that is already on file
$sql2 = "SELECT distinct Action from qci_dmlog_data WHERE LogID = '$updLogID'";
$result2 = $db->query($sql2) or die('<p>Query to get existing Follow Up Action from qci_dmlog_data table failed: ' . mysqli_error() . '</p>');

while ($row = $result2->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $old_action = $row["Action"];
}

$line_insert = '<br /><strong>[Follow-Up Action]</strong> '.$_SESSION['User_Last'].', '.$_SESSION['User_First'].' - '.date('Y-m-d H:i').'<br />';
$updAction = $old_action . $line_insert . $updAction;
```

The final `$updAction` variable basically consists of the old content + line break info + new content and is then written back into the database

Comment: That's strange... Line breaks in a text area should produce `\n`, not `<br>`. How do you fetch the content of the writable textarea?

Comment: how are you adding this data to your textbox ?

Comment: @UsmanRana a modal is launched and then via AJAX populated with the latest record on file from the database. The user makes changes, presses "Save Record" and then the newly entered update is appended to the old one and written back into the database.

Comment: Oh.. so it's you who add those <br>! A textarea does not display HTML but plain text. So, either you use a div to display the content (in which case you will have to convert the `\n` into `<br>` for the text typed in by the user), or you use plain text (=no tags) in your message.

Comment: right, so the root cause is that `$line_insert = '<br /><strong>[Follow-Up Action]</strong>` enters `<br>` tags that are not supported by the `<textarea>`, got it. Is there any way I can add `\n` to add a linebreak without relying on html?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/j747c25t/2/) I just made

Here is the javascript I used for my example:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://baconipsum.com/api/?type=all-meat&paras=3&start-with-lorem=1&format=html",
  method: "GET",
  dataType: "HTML",
  success: function(data) {

    console.log(data);

    $("#raw").text(data);

    $("textarea").html( data.replace(/<p>/g, '').replace(/<\/p>/g, "&#10;") );
  } 

})
```

But you should replace the `<br>` and `\n` tags instead for the line break so:

```
.replace(/<br>|\n/g, "&#10;")
```

The `"&#10;` is an [**HTML Entities<sup>Wikipédia</sup>**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) for the Line Feed, there is also `&#13;` for the carriage return which you can use.

Comment: I have to upvote this solution just for the use of the `bacon` dolor lipsum text :) I will fiddle around with the replacement tag and see how it goes, JS is not option for me as the content sits in a modal and I dont know how to apply this (I am no good with JS)...